# Why is fixed argument of anonymous function not updated, if this variable has changed between calls?

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

Developing an optimization script, I realized Matlab does not handle secondary arguments of anonymous functions as I expected.

Consider this simple MWE:

```
%% Define basic parameters
daysTotal       = 3;
hoursTotal      = daysTotal*24;
nhi             = 4;        % Third argument, does not change.
intervalsTotal  = hoursTotal*nhi;
q_in_mean       = 0.82;

% Original definition of var2
var2            = zeros(hoursTotal, 1);
var2(2:2:end)   = 1;        % Second argument, does change!

var1_initial = var2.*q_in_mean/12; % Initial version of first argument

%% Define anonymous function
objFun          = @(var1) objFunModel(var1, var2, nhi);

%% Call objFun for the first time
objFun(var1_initial); % Result of sum(var2) = 36, which is correct.

%% Change var2
var2            = zeros(hoursTotal, 1);
var2(4:4:end)   = 1;

%% Call objFun again
objFun(var1_initial); % Result of sum(var2) is still 36 inside objFunModel
sum(var2) % Actual value of sum(var2) = 18 after change!

%% Separate functions
function varStd = objFunModel(var1, var2, nhi)
    sum(var2)
    varRes  = cumsum(2*var1 - 0.12*var2);
    varStd  = std(varRes);
end
```

Though `var2` is changed between both function calls, it is *not* updated as you can see in the terminal output.
Is this the intended behavior, or a bug?
In case of the former, what can I do to force `var2` to be updated inside `objFunModel`? Define the anonymous function again?

Comment: It’s intended behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an anonymous function, the variables that are not in the parenthesis following the @ (`var2` and `nhi` in your example), are passed by value, not by reference. Thus, MATLAB has no way of knowing that the variable changed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So I'll use `objFun = @(var1, var2) objFunModel(var1, var2, nhi)` to define the anonymous function instead, and call it as `objFun(var1_initial, var2)`. When needed in an optimization, I'll use `@(var1) objFun(var1, var2)`.